# CSS transition value causes transform:rotate to snap when tracking mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently practising using animations in JavaScript/React to include some "interactivity" in a static page. I am struggling with a component which is essentially an arrow which spins to point to the user's cursor, when using the CSS transition property, the arrow snaps around as the result from the trigonometric calculation flips from 225deg to -135deg (I assume because of CAST rule in trigonometry?).

HTML

```
<section className='home' ref={ref}>

  <div className='intro'>
    <div className='image-section' ref={positionRef}>
      <div className='spinny-thing' style={{transform: `rotate(${angle}deg)`}} ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

ReactJS

```
// Mouse Positioning
  const [mousePostion, ref] = useMousePosition(0, 0, 30)

  const positionRef = React.useRef()

  // Image div positioning
  const [xPosition, setXPosition] = React.useState(null)
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = React.useState(null)

  const getPosition = () => {
    const x = positionRef.current.offsetLeft
    setXPosition(x + (positionRef.current.offsetWidth / 2))
    const y = positionRef.current.offsetTop
    setYPosition(y + (positionRef.current.offsetHeight / 2))
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getPosition()
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", getPosition)
  }, [])

  const [angle, setAngle] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let mouse_angle = (Math.atan2(mousePostion.pageY - yPosition, mousePostion.pageX - xPosition)) * (180 / Math.PI ) + 45

    setAngle(mouse_angle)
  }, [mousePostion])
```

Please note the + 45 in the mouse_angle calculation is to shift the pointer away from the initial corner and towards the mouse (as the arrow in the div is positioned on a corner).

CSS

```
.spinny-thing {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 50% 15px 50% 50%;
    transition: all .1s ease;    
}
```

I have tried solving the problem with an if statement based on if the mouse_angle result is positive or negative, but this only shifts the snapping to another location.

Removing the CSS transition of .1s of course solves the problem, but then it does not rotate smoothly.

I am hoping for a solution which removes the snapping from the rotation where negative angles become positive and vice versa, whilst maintaining a smooth transition.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Sorry, useMousePosition is from npm package react-hook/mouse-position

```
import useMousePosition from '@react-hook/mouse-position'
```

Comment: What is useMousePosition?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post.

Comment: Math.atan2 returns a value between -pi and pi.  If the value was increasing, and almost pi, it would flip around to -pi.  You would need to add 2pi in this situation, and subtract 2pi in the inverse situation.